# Kendo UI bug with jQuery versions

Tags: grid, window, filtering, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI grid and a Kendo UI Window on the same page. The window contains form elements for record insertion, a record being represented by a row in the grid. But for reasons not known by me, when I opened the window and closed it again and then reopened, Kendo UI scaled it to be 100x smaller. I didn't want to hack the window, so I've looked for alternative solution.

I've used jQuery 1.7.2. I've updated jQuery to version 1.8.0. and window opening, closing and reopening worked. I was very happy until I realized that now the grid filters are not working. When I click on a grid filter, nothing happens, no popup, nothing. What is the cause of this and what would be the solution?

EDIT:

This is my code (I've replaced the values of the Urls). Grid filters are working with jQuery 1.7.2. and window reopen works with new versions of jQuery. Also, if I remove the sort hack, the grid filter popup still doesn't show up.

```
    var hshflt = {};
    var addWindow;
    var editWindow;
    var init = false;
    //Sort Hack

    /*
    Changes all dataSources to case insensitive sorting (client side sorting).
    This snipped enable case insensitive sorting on Kendo UI grid, too.

    The original case sensitive comparer is a private and can't be accessed without modifying the original source code.
    tested with Kendo UI version 2012.2.710 (Q2 2012 / July 2012).
    */

    var CaseInsensitiveComparer = {

        getterCache: {},

        getter: function (expression) {
            return this.getterCache[expression] = this.getterCache[expression] || new Function("d", "return " + kendo.expr(expression));
        },

        selector: function (field) {
            return jQuery.isFunction(field) ? field : this.getter(field);
        },

        asc: function (field) {
            var selector = this.selector(field);
            return function (a, b) {

                if ((selector(a).toLowerCase) && (selector(b).toLowerCase)) {
                    a = selector(a).toLowerCase(); // the magical part
                    b = selector(b).toLowerCase();
                }

                return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
            };
        },

        desc: function (field) {
            var selector = this.selector(field);
            return function (a, b) {

                if ((selector(a).toLowerCase) && (selector(b).toLowerCase)) {
                    a = selector(a).toLowerCase(); // the magical part
                    b = selector(b).toLowerCase();
                }

                return a < b ? 1 : (a > b ? -1 : 0);
            };
        },

        create: function (descriptor) {
            return this[descriptor.dir.toLowerCase()](descriptor.field);
        },


        combine: function (comparers) {
            return function (a, b) {
                var result = comparers[0](a, b),
        idx,
        length;

                for (idx = 1, length = comparers.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                    result = result || comparers[idx](a, b);
                }

                return result;
            };
        }
    };

    kendo.data.Query.prototype.normalizeSort = function (field, dir) {
        if (field) {
            var descriptor = typeof field === "string" ? { field: field, dir: dir} : field,
    descriptors = jQuery.isArray(descriptor) ? descriptor : (descriptor !== undefined ? [descriptor] : []);

            return jQuery.grep(descriptors, function (d) { return !!d.dir; });
        }
    };

    kendo.data.Query.prototype.sort = function (field, dir, comparer) {

        var idx,
length,
descriptors = this.normalizeSort(field, dir),
comparers = [];

        comparer = comparer || CaseInsensitiveComparer;

        if (descriptors.length) {
            for (idx = 0, length = descriptors.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                comparers.push(comparer.create(descriptors[idx]));
            }

            return this.orderBy({ compare: comparer.combine(comparers) });
        }

        return this;
    };

    kendo.data.Query.prototype.orderBy = function (selector) {

        var result = this.data.slice(0),
comparer = jQuery.isFunction(selector) || !selector ? CaseInsensitiveComparer.asc(selector) : selector.compare;

        return new kendo.data.Query(result.sort(comparer));
    };

    kendo.data.Query.prototype.orderByDescending = function (selector) {

        return new kendo.data.Query(this.data.slice(0).sort(CaseInsensitiveComparer.desc(selector)));
    };
    //Sort Hack

    $("#refresh-btn").click(function () {
        refreshGrid();
    });

    var grid;

    function getPageIndex() {
        if (!(grid)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return grid.pager.page() - 1;
    }

    function getPageSize() {
        if (!(grid)) {
            return 10;
        }
        return grid.pager.pageSize();
    }

    function getFilters() {
        if (!(grid)) {
            return "";
        }
        return grid.dataSource.filter();
    }

    function getSorts() {
        if (!(grid)) {
            return "";
        }
        var arr = grid.dataSource.sort();
        if ((arr) && (arr.length == 0)) {
            return "";
        }
        var returnValue = "";
        for (var index in arr) {
            var type = "";
            for (var col in grid.columns) {
                if (grid.columns[col].field === arr[index].field) {
                    type = grid.columns[col].type;
                }
            }
            returnValue += ((returnValue.length > 0) ? (";") : ("")) + arr[index].field + "," + (arr[index].dir === "asc") + "," + type;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    function getColumns() {
        if (!(grid)) {
            return "";
        }
        var columns = "";
        for (var col in grid.columns) {
            if (columns.length > 0) {
                columns += ";";
            }
            columns += grid.columns[col].field + "," + grid.columns[col].type;
        }
        return columns;
    }

    var initGrid = true;
    var grid2Data;

    function getDataSource() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mydsurl' + getParams(),
            data: "filter=" + JSON.stringify(getFilters()) + "&columns=" + getColumns(),
            success: function (param) { grid2Data = param; },
            //dataType: dataType,
            async: false
        });
        return grid2Data.Data;
    }

    var shouldClickOnRefresh = false;
    function refreshGrid() {
        shouldClickOnRefresh = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mydsurl' + getParams(),
            data: "filter=" + JSON.stringify(getFilters()) + "&columns=" + getColumns(),
            success: function (param) { grid2Data = param; },
            //dataType: dataType,
            async: false
        });
        grid.dataSource.total = function () {
            return grid2Data.Total;
        }
        for (var col in grid.columns) {
            if ((grid.columns[col].type) && (grid.columns[col].type === "Date")) {
                for (var row in grid2Data.Data) {
                    grid2Data.Data[row][grid.columns[col].field] = new Date(parseInt((grid2Data.Data[row][grid.columns[col].field] + "").replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")));
                }
            }
        }
        grid.dataSource.data(grid2Data.Data);
        shouldClickOnRefresh = true;
    }

    function getParams() {
        return getPageSize() + "|" + getPageIndex() + "|" + getSorts();
    }

    function bindGrid() {
        var editUrl = 'myediturl';
        if (!(editWindow)) {
            editWindow = $("#edit-window");
        }
        $(".k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-edit").each(function (index) {
            $(this).click(function () {
                if (!editWindow.data("kendoWindow")) {
                    editWindow.kendoWindow({
                        title: "Edit User",
                        width: "60%",
                        height: "60%",
                        close: onClose,
                        open: onEditOpen,
                        content: editUrl + $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()[index]["ID"]
                    });
                }
                else {

                    editWindow.data("kendoWindow").refresh(editUrl + $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()[index]["ID"]);
                    editWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
                }
                editWindow.data("kendoWindow").center();
                return false;
            })
        });
        $(".k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-delete").each(function (index) {
            $(this).click(function () {

                var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?");
                if (r == true) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'mydelurl' + $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()[index]["ID"],
                        success: function (param) { refreshGrid(); },
                        async: false
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    function onDataBound() {
        if (!(shouldClickOnRefresh)) {
            shouldClickOnRefresh = true;
            bindGrid();
        }
        else {
            refreshGrid();
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataBound: onDataBound,
            dataSource: {
                autoSync: true,
                data: getDataSource(),
                serverPaging: true,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Email: { type: "string" },
                            FullName: { type: "string" },
                            LogCreateDate: { type: "date" },
                            RoleName: { type: "string" },
                            UserName: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    },
                    total: function (response) {
                        return grid2Data.Total;
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            toolbar: ["create"],
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            columns: [
                    {
                        command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                        title: "&nbsp;"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Email",
                        title: "Email",
                        type: "String"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "FullName",
                        title: "Full Name",
                        type: "String"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "LogCreateDate",
                        title: "Created",
                        type: "Date",
                        template: '#= kendo.toString(LogCreateDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'
                    },
                    {
                        field: "RoleName",
                        title: "Role",
                        type: "Custom"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "UserName",
                        type: "String"
                    }
                ],
            editable: "popup"
        });
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        function onAddOpen() {
        }



        addWindow = $("#add-window");
        $(".k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-add").click(function () {
            if (!addWindow.data("kendoWindow")) {
                addWindow.kendoWindow({
                    title: "Add User",
                    width: "60%",
                    height: "60%",
                    close: onClose,
                    open: onAddOpen,
                    content: 'myaddurl'
                });
            }
            else {
                addWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
            }
            addWindow.data("kendoWindow").center();
            addWindow.data("kendoWindow").refresh();
            return false;
        });

    });

    function onClose() {
        $("#refresh-btn").click();
    }

    function onEditOpen() {
        //editWindow.data("kendoWdinow").center();
    }
```

Comment: If you think that it's a problem with `jquery` version, why do you use one version that is not the one packed in `kendoui.web.2012.3.1114.open-source.zip` (1.8.2)?

Comment: I don't know what is the bug, I only described my experience in the question. I think I've tried with that too, but I'm not sure as I've tried many things yesterday. I will try this again and will let you know. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think that this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hmaTx/2/) is more or less what you have (other than the `window` does not contain a `form`) and it works!, Please, check if this is more or less what you have and if something is different maybe it helps you.

Comment: I've edited my question. As you can see, there are some differences between my code and your code. Your code didn't have a filter, but if I put filterable: true, into your properties, the filter works. But I don't want to bind my grid locally, I need to load a page in my window, I need case-insensitive sorting and so on, so if I modify my page to be like yours I believe both the window and the grid will work, but my page will not fulfill my needs. Really I don't understand what's wrong with my code, why the grid popup doesn't show up? Am I misusing the technology, or is this a bug?

Comment: I believe this is a bug, because the grid filter popup should open whenever I click on them unless I actively write code to prevent that. I've hacked the sorting feature, that's true, but only because of another kendo ui grid bug, namely it doesn't support case-insensitive sorting. Also, I've handled the communication instead of Kendo UI, but that shouldn't be a problem, should it? Finally, I've tested with jQuery version 1.8.2., but unfortunately this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I either need to have a solution for this problem, or a temporary solution and information about the time when the final solution will be finished (approximatively). If I don't manage to find an elegant solution for this, I will tell my client to use something else, because case-insensitivity is not supported (which makes it difficult to sort), window reopening puts a scale of 0.01 (???) into the window's settings, it doesn't support lazy filtering (which would be useful if you have large data-sets) and the filter buttons don't work with new versions of jQuery.

Comment: I would really like to conclude my research as a success and to be able to recommend Kendo UI to my client and other people as well, but I need to see some good news regarding to this problem, which is essentially the last barrier. Of course, if there will be a solution to the filter button problem I will temporarily hack the window usage and will use jQuery 1.7.2 with this version of Kendo UI. Also, if I've misused kendo UI, I will correct my mistake(s), but where did I mis-use kendo? And if I did so, why did it work with jQuery 1.7.2?

Comment: Also, can you tell me which version of Kendo was used in your fiddle? Thank you.

Comment: If you check `resources` in the fiddle you can  check exactly what I'm loading. It is: http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.all.min.js

Comment: Thank you, I have the same version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've hacked Kendo UI for the second time, this time I've solved its incompatibility with jQuery 1.8.3. using the following hack:

```
$(".k-grid-filter").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $($(".k-filter-menu.k-popup.k-group.k-reset")[index]).offset({
            left: $($(".k-grid-filter")[index]).offset().left - $($(".k-filter-menu.k-popup.k-group.k-reset")[index]).width(), 
            top: $($(".k-grid-filter")[index]).offset().top + $($(".k-grid-filter")[index]).height()})
        })
    });
```

I've put this hack into the document load event of the page an voila, it works. It surely looks ugly as hell with this hack, but after designing it will look good as new. I'm happy I found a work around, but I'm unhappy I had to hack Kendo UI twice. It is a very nice tool except the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.8.# is only compatible with Kendo UI - Q2 2012 SP1 (2012.2 913) or later..

If your kendo UI version is earlier, you should update it.

Comment: I have an open-source version of kendoui.web.2012.3.1114.open-source. Isn't this version newer than version 2012.2.913?

Comment: In the documentation, the dependencies state that a minimum of jQuery 1.8.2 is required for your version. Try and let me know...

Comment: I've tried with version 1.8.3 and the problem was not fixed with this upgrade.

Comment: Are you shure that version of `kendo.grid.min.js` is 2012.3.1114? I had the same problem like you, and I solved it upgrading Kendo. ( BTW I'm using jquery 1.8.0 and Kendo UI Beta v2012.3.1024)

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The download file is kendoui.web.2012.3.1114.open-source.zip.